# Problem about finding the same number of a given number in list LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

so i was trying to take two arguments, a list and a number and returns true if and only if the number is equal to any element in the list

```
(defun find-num(a z)
    (if (= z (car a)) (write t))
    (if (not(= z (car a))) (find-num (cdr a)) )
    (if (not(= z (car a))) (write f) )
    )

(find-num '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
```

so i assumed the code will do such steps
if z is equal to a , return true,
if z is not equal to a , write f (return false) or jump into a recursive function which finds the number in the rest of the lists until it finds the same number

however, i received such error

```
VAL/APPLY: Too few arguments (1 instead of at least 2) given to
      FIND-NUM
```

i'm not sure whether which part is messed up

i tried to use cond statement, but received the same error as well

```
(defun find-num(a z)
    (cond
    ( (= z (car a)) (write t) )
    ( (not(= z (car a))) (find-num (cdr a)) ) 
    ( (not(= z (car a))) (write f) )
        )
    )

(find-num '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear, isn't it?

> Too few arguments (1 instead of at least 2) given to FIND-NUM

You are calling the function `FIND-NUM` with one argument, but the function requires two. Your function has the parameters `a` and `z`. That's two. But your recursive call is `(find-num (cdr a))`. That's just one argument: the value of `(cdr a)`.

Another problem: `f` is not the value for *false* in Lisp. `f` is an undefined variable. Evaluate `(not t)` to see what the *false* value in Lisp really is.

```
CL-USER > (not t)
```

What might be the result?

Then next you will need to check if your function returns the correct result.

Comment: Thanks, i've found the problem, my own careless mistake, i should put (find-num (cdr a) z).

Comment: (not t) is same as nil, so can i guess i can just replace it with nil or (print () )

Comment: A Lisp compiler will replace `(not t)` by `nil` for you; but a good reason to do that anyway is to keep the code free of such verbiage.

Comment: sure, i think i will just keep it empty instead

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun find-num (arr num)
  (cond ((null arr) nil)              ;; if no arr element equals num -> nil
        ((= (car arr) num) t)         ;; if first element of array equals num -> t
        (t (find-num (cdr arr) num)))) ;; otherwise search in rest of arry for num
```

Comment: i guess this also works:


(defun find-num(a z)
    (cond 
        ( (= 0 (length a)) (write ()) )
        ( (= z (car a)) (write #\t) )
        ; Otherwise loop
        (t (find-num (cdr a) z))
        )
    )

(find-num '(1 2 3 4) 22)

Comment: you don't need `write` - let the function return the values (in common lisp you don't need explicite `return`).

Comment: `(= 0 (length a)` is in fact `(null a)` - `null` will be more efficient. `#\t` is the letter "t" and not the object `t` (True) so be careful!

Comment: if you really want to use `write` then you have to use `(write t)` and not `(write #\t)`.

Comment: `(type-of t)` => BOOLEAN, `(type-of #\t)` => STANDARD-CHAR - but in conditionals you `#\t` is treated like `t` because everything non-`nil` is counted as `t`. But it is not a BOOLEAN - and it will bite you some day. `(eq #\t t)` => NIL and `(eql #\t t)` => NIL

Comment: Sure, to keep it efficient, i think i have to optimize the uses of these codes as you do , thanks for your assist and helpful reviews !